# Variable increasing in value rather than decreasing

Tags: c++, math

I am working on some simulation software, in which I have an entity that is spiraling around a particular point.

As the entity starts spiraling around the point, and the radius of the spiral continues to grow, I want to display the number of circuits that the entity has completed to the user (completion of a circuit is defined as the location/ time at which the entity reaches the same angle from the origin that it was at when it started spiralling).
I also want to display to the user, the distance from the aircraft's current location to the point at which it will complete the current circuit.

I am doing this using the following section of code:

```
if (m_OVF_TURN_DIR == TURN_LEFT)
    {
        arcAngle = 360 - (NormalAngle360(NormalAngle360(ldFAZ_CentrePos_AC) + NormalAngle360(m_circuitStartAngle))); 
        m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = (arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius);
    }
    else
    {
        arcAngle = 360 - (NormalAngle360(NormalAngle360(m_circuitStartAngle) + NormalAngle360(ldFAZ_CentrePos_AC))); 
        m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = ((arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius) / 180.0); // Nm
    }
```

In this code, the lines:

```
m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = (arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius);
```

and

```
m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = ((arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius) / 180.0);
```

are what is calculating the distance from the aircraft's current location to the point at which it will complete a circuit.

The first block is used to calculate the distance when the entity is spiraling in an anti-clockwise direction, and the second block is used when the entity is spiraling in a clockwise direction.

The clockwise direction seems to be working correctly- it displays a number for the distance to go, and this number decreases steadily as the entity follows the path of the spiral. However, the anti-clockwise direction seems to start at a random number, and then increase steadily as the entity follows the path of the spiral... rather than decrease as it should (because the entity is moving closer to the point at which the circuit will be completed).

This suggests to me that I am using an incorrect symbol somewhere in this block (+, -, * or /), but I can't seem to figure out where... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The function `NormalAngle360()` is defined with:

```
double NormalAngle360(const double aInAngle)
{
    //## Operation [c0b17aaa-bda1-4164-8ba7-5f960c924a32]
    double ldAngle = NormalAngle(aInAngle);
    if (ldAngle < 0.0) 
        ldAngle += 360.0;
    return ldAngle;
    //## Operation End
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for NormalAngle360

Comment: Code for `NormalAngle360` added.

Comment: Code where m_currentRadius is being modified and declared. Most probably something is wrong with this variable, i think it is not getting decreased at all.

Comment: The thing is that it does work when the entity is moving in a clockwise direction... just not when it's moving in an anticlockwise direction..

Comment: Umm.. sorry but in this case i guess you would have to show the whole code here for detecting whats wrong with the logic.

Comment: That is the whole code for calculating the `distanceToGo`... the first statement, that fulfills the condition works correctly- it's just the code inside the `else` statement that doesn't seem to be working correctly for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Since you normalize the angle such that it lies between `0` and `360`, there should only be two possibilities. Either the angle starts at some value and decreases to `0`, in which case

```
m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = (arcAngle/180 * PI * m_currentRadius);
```

should work, or the angle starts at some value and increases up to `360`, in which case

```
m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = ((360 - arcAngle)/180 * PI * m_currentRadius);
```

should work.

It's possible that you can use the first version for both cases.

If both versions don't work, I think the angle is not what it should be. Maybe you could output the values of `arcAngle` to check that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I gave your suggestion for the anti-clockwise distance a go, but it is still starting at a seemingly random value (it may well be the actual distance of the arc), but then increasing rather tha decreasing as the aircraft follows the arc. However, after making the change you suggested here, it seems to be increasing more rapidly than before...

Comment: Ok. Can you tell where `arcAngle` starts, and if it's increasing or decreasing, for both cases, please?

Comment: `arcAngle` is the angle between two lines (line A from the centre of the spiral to the entity's current position, and line B from the centre of the spiral to the end of the arc that starts at the entity's current position). The length of the arc is calculated dependent on the speed at which the entity is moving, and its distance from the centre of the spiral. I am working with arcs as sections of a circle- so if the arc starts at a point X, and extends clockwise, it's angle will increase the further along the circle it travels. If it extends anticlockwise, its angle will decrease.

Comment: I am using the difference btween the original angle, and the final angle when trying to calculate the `distanceToGo`, whether that has increased or decreased... When it has increased seems to be working (i.e. when the entity is moving clockwise), but I can't seem to get the logic right for when it has decreased (i.e. when the entity is moving anticlockwise)....

Answer (score 0):

The lines in your if...else branches both do the same thing:

```
    arcAngle = 360 - (NormalAngle360(NormalAngle360(ldFAZ_CentrePos_AC) + NormalAngle360(m_circuitStartAngle))); 

    arcAngle = 360 - (NormalAngle360(NormalAngle360(m_circuitStartAngle) + NormalAngle360(ldFAZ_CentrePos_AC)));
```

because `360 - (a+b)` is the same as `360 - (b+a)`. You'll need to rethink this logic.

Also you do not need the two inner calls to NormalAngle360, the line could be written as:

```
arcAngle = 360 - NormalAngle360( ldLAZ_CentrePos_AC + m_circuitStartAngle );
```

Perhaps what you're looking for is just changing `+` to `-` here; and/or taking out the `360 -`.

Also, the `NormalAngle360` function should check if the angle `>= 360.0` and subtract `360` from it.

Comment: The lines in my if... else don't quite do the same thing- the `else` clause calculates the distance with `((arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius) / 180.0); `, whereas the `if` calculates the distance with: `m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = (arcAngle * PI * m_currentRadius);`. The `else` clause, which is calculating the distance when the entity is moving in a clockwise direcion works correctly- the value it displays for the distance is correct, and it counts down to 0 as the entity approaches the end of he arc. However, the `if` doesn't quite work correctly- the value it displays counts up instead of down

Comment: The difference between the `if` and `else` is that in the `else` I am dividing the value by 180... but I' not sure what I should be doing in the `if`, and why the value it generates increases as the entity approaches the end of the arc, rather than decreases...?

Comment: @someone2088 The quoted lines do the same thing. If that's intentional then you could do that calculation before the `if`. It suggests to me that you aren't doing the right calculation though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue- the problem was that I had missed out a `-` sign from the function being called in the `if` clause of the statement:

```
if (m_OVF_TURN_DIR == TURN_LEFT)
    {
        arcAngle = 360 - fabs((NormalAngle360(-NormalAngle360(ldFAZ_CentrePos_AC) + NormalAngle360(m_circuitStartAngle)))); 
        m_SteerData.DistanceToGo = (arcAngle/180 * PI * m_currentRadius);  
    }
```

Using `-NormalAngle360(...) in the innermost bracket here resolved the issue that I was having.